# Best and simplest way in golang to defer email sending to a queue

Tags: go

Were running a simple web application on Amazon EC2, cassandra as the database.

It would be good if the user signup email could be deferred/queued, and maybe even rate limited.

What is the most "go like" way to achieve this without making things too complicated? I know there are lots of queue/task/worker like solutions, but I am more interested in something that is lightweight.

Comment: Why not use Amazon Simple Email Service or Mandrill instead of doing this locally? You will probably find that a lot of emails from naked EC2 boxes will bounce anyway. Mandrill allows you to send "async", which means you can avoid having the user wait for the API to respond before loading the next page.

Comment: Yep, were using the amazon mail service already. Don't want http requests to block waiting for the amazon mail service. Probably need to rate limit the queue as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have 1 goroutine to handle the emails and communicate with it using channels, for example :

```
var emailch = make(chan *UserInfo) 
//you could make it buffered, that way it will block if requests are coming too fast
//var emailch = make(chan *UserInfo, 1000)

func init() {
    go func() {
        for ui := range emailch {
            send_email(ui.Email)
        }
    }()
}

func Register(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    //code
    emailch <- &UserInfo{....}
}
```

Comment: Yep I thought about this, but it doesnt really deal with the case where you might need to restart your app, the queue would be gone right?

Comment: @Jacob yes but that will always be your problem, you can simply cut down the queue size or move it to an external queueing software (which can crash). Use a variable pool of dispatcher goroutines that asynchronously dispatch your mails to SES, this way you can control the queue length and the amount of lost information.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completion, I would like to add that the above code does not create a unbuffered Channel. The comments indicate this in some way.

> //you could make it buffered, that way it will block if requests are coming too fast
>
> //var emailch = make(chan *UserInfo, 1000)

The above Code `make(chan *UserInfo)` creates a channel with a buffer of size 0. This is not an unbuffered channel, it will block the first sending until it is Receiver.

The comments regarding buffering are not false, but some kind of misleading.

On this page you can learn more about channels and try interactively.
https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2

https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3